# button click stops app unexpectedly

Tags: android, android-activity, onclick

I have a button which is supposed to open a new activity:

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
  switch (view.getId()) {
  case R.id.Button01:
   Intent myIntent = new Intent(LFSQL02.this, ManageFilms.class);
   startActivity(myIntent);
   break;
  }
 }
```

When pressed, it leads to an unexpected stop. The manifest does list .ManageFilms class. Where is the error? Thanks

Comment: [2011-01-01 13:59:28 - LFSQL02] Starting activity info.domain.LFSQL02.LFSQL02 on device emulator-5554
[2011-01-01 13:59:32 - LFSQL02] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=info.domain.LFSQL02/.LFSQL02 }
[2011-01-01 13:59:32 - LFSQL02] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front

Comment: ... then when I press on the button, the app stops with the error warning, and no new item shows in the logcat

Comment: That's not the logcat. Post the stacktrace from your logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the activity to the manifest.xml file?
Open up AndroidManifest.xml > application > in application nodes click add > search/type your activity class name and save it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Button button_name=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id)
button_name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{
public void onClick(view v) {
Intent intent_name=new Intent(getApplicationcontext(), activity_name.class);
startActivity(intent_name);
}
});
```

This works for me...try this out.....

Comment: Can you please explain the answer?

Comment: @Girish Sortur button_name is whatever you want to name eg T and button_id is the id your button has in the xml file and activity_name is the name of the activity  that you want to go to on clicking the button..and intent_name is the name you want to give to your intent eg i......I hope this was helpful to you....